# how many days it will take to get pain away?

Tags: gym, pain, doms

I have joined the gym yesterday as a beginner. In the gym, what they asked me to with machines I have done. From that moment my joints and neck are getting sore and today this pain increased. So my question is when this pain will go away? Does this take forever or some days? Today is my leg day so I guess my legs will get sore today too :(

I have never done such physical activity, except dance, it does create soreness in the body for one day only So I have no idea of this soreness.

Comment: Do you mean until you don't feel sore anymore in this one instance or until exercising doesn't make you feel sore anymore? The thing is, both depend on a lot of things, nobody can say: It will take 102 days until physical activity doesn't make you feel super sore and hurting anymore. I guess the acute issue will go away in a couple of days, up to maybe a week or even two if you've trained super intense on multiple days. And the general doms issue will be over in a couple of months or perhaps never, depending on what you do and how often you do it (more often usually means less doms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal to feel muscle tension / soreness after a workout, in fact it *(usually)* means that you had a pretty good workout, at least effort wise - obviously though, with incorrect technique, albeit you might get muscle soreness you might create long-term issues.

An average muscle soreness usually lasts from **24 up to 72 hours**, however just because it may last longer does not mean there's anything wrong with your body.

I'd also add the following (useful) tidbits:

- Muscle soreness is primarily caused by **eccentric** exercise *(lengthening of the muscle)*. An iso-metric exercise is a good workout alternative during muscle-soreness which will cause a bit less muscle-soreness. This obviously does not mean, eccentric exercise should be replaced by isometric one. While it is a cliche, the *"no pain, no gain"* saying has a merit of truth to it.
- During extreme muscle soreness a good massage, sauna or even a **hot bath/shower** will always help!
- In general, your body is not used to having to putting out such effort (and it does not like it) - in fact, you may not known, but actually muscle growth is cuased by doing a *(good sort of)* damage to your muscles and tears, which the muscles have to re-grow. Over the course of time with a **regular workout schedule**, your body will get used to it and **become more tolerant** the muscle-soreness
- And a stable of any fittness advice, good **nutrition** and providing your body with enough rest (**sleep**) is always an absolute must!

Overall, don't fear too much.  It'll be most likely pretty much gone in a day or two :)